# get notification using qt-android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I want get notification from my app using qt-android, I found [this examole](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html) in qt examples , it's in QML and I want use it in QWidgets,To use code in QWidget I changed it as follow:

**notificationclient.h**

```
#ifndef NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H
#define NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H

#include <QObject>

class NotificationClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NotificationClient(QObject *parent = 0);

    void setNotification(QString notification);
    QString notification() const;

signals:
    void notificationChanged();

private slots:
    void updateAndroidNotification();

private:
    QString m_notification;
};

#endif // NOTIFICATIONCLIENT_H
```

**notificationclient.cpp**

```
#include "notificationclient.h"

#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidJniObject>

NotificationClient::NotificationClient(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(notificationChanged()), this, SLOT(updateAndroidNotification()));
    m_notification = "";
}

void NotificationClient::setNotification(QString notification)
{
    if (m_notification == notification)
        return;

    m_notification = notification;
    emit notificationChanged();
}

QString NotificationClient::notification() const
{
    return m_notification;
}

void NotificationClient::updateAndroidNotification()
{
    QAndroidJniObject javaNotification = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(m_notification);
    QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod<void>("org/qtproject/example/notification/NotificationClient",
                                       "notify",
                                       "(Ljava/lang/String;)V",
                                       javaNotification.object<jstring>());
}
```

For use in Main class:

```
notification = new NotificationClient(this);
```

And for get notification:

```
void myclass::on_btn_clicked(){
notification->setNotification("hello world");
}
```

and follow code in .pro file too:

```
ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android
QT       += core gui androidextras
```

when `on_btn_clicked()` called the program suddenly exits

NOTE:[This is the java code](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-android-sources-src-org-qtproject-example-notification-notificationclient-java.html) and I set package name with my app package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem , we should add this attribute to activity tag in AndroidMainifest.xml

```
android:name="MY.APP.PACKAGE.NAME.NotificationClient"
```

Comment: Hello please can you give me the full syntax of it to add to AndroidMainifest.xml

Comment: i mean where exactly to add it in AndroidMainifest.xml and how Thanks